# App crashing with error +[UIStatusBar frameForStyle:orientation:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I'm working on an app which was made in some older version of Xcode, it is currently having min supported version **iOS 7.0**

`+[UIStatusBar frameForStyle:orientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I have set the break point, but unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for your responses and interest, Accidentally I came to know that, I had set the **UIStatusBar** hidden, while there was a MPVloumeView added to view, Whenever I tried to change the volume, It crashed the application. According to another SO answer, the MPVloumeView should be in the first UIWindow of application.

I just added another MPVloumeView in first window, and made it invisible

```
MPVolumeView* mpView=[[MPVolumeView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
[mpView setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
mpView.alpha=0.01;
{
    NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
    if (windows.count > 0) {
        [[windows objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:mpView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no class reference for UIStatusBar, so you are calling a class method on an unknown class.

What are you trying to do with the status bar?  You can edit it through the plist or through UIApplication like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`

It does look like (from looking at code on GitHub) that UIStatusBar.h was part of UIKit at some point.  Maybe it is a private class that we should not really have access to?

Comment: App is not calling it specifically. Some other UI change in status bar is causing it to be called and it throws exception there.

Comment: Try turning zombies on and see if you can trace back to why the crash is happening.   If you need help sorting through the output, try pasting it here.

Comment: Thanks, I try it with zombies.